# Swipe Gesture in Collection Cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a swipe gesture inside of a collection view cell. I tried to utilize this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ_Ke0dYpdw but it's not for collection cells and I don't know how to make it work there. Here's the code I have so far:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell

cell.delegate = self
cell.index = indexPath.row
var eventsClass = PFObject(className: EVENTS_CLASS_NAME)
eventsClass = eventsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

//swipe gesture
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(_:)))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(_:)))

leftSwipe.direction = .left
rightSwipe.direction = .right

cell.popoverView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
cell.popoverView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

   func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let eventCell = EventCell()

    if (sender.direction == .left) {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }

    if (sender.direction == .right) {
        print("Swipe Right")
        //let popoverView = CGPointMake(EventCell.popoverView.frame.origin.x + 50.0, self.popoverView.frame.origin.y);
       // popoverView.frame = CGRectMake(popoverView.x, popoverView.y, self.popoverView.frame.size.width, self.popoverView.frame.size.height)
        //popoverView.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

This gives me the **error**:

> 'Value of type 'Home' has no member 'handleSwipes'' on the
>   action:#selector line

Comment: Have you tried taking the handleSwipes function outside the cellForItemAt method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `@objc` annotation as well as the `_` syntax to your function definition. If you do not add `_`its Objective-C name will be `functionNameWithSender:` instead of `functionName`. So your function definition should read:

`@objc func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)`